# How to retrieve Unicode string from sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am saving records into sqlite database in two tables. when retrieving data using class object, It's OK, but when I create a view and select from view. the result is always zero records. I went on checking fields and I finally find out that the column which saves value in uft8 causes the problem.

My class

```
public class Translation
    {
        string _ayaID, _text;
        byte _chapterID, _languageID;
        System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment _hAlignment;

        public string ArabicAyaID
        {
            get { return _ayaID; }
            set { _ayaID = value; }
        }
        public string ArabicAyaTranslation
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }
        public byte LanguageID
        {
            get { return _languageID; }
            set { _languageID = value; }
        }
        public byte ChapterID
        {
            get { return _chapterID; }
            set { _chapterID = value; }
        }
        public System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment HAlignment
        {
            get { return _hAlignment; }
            set { _hAlignment = value; }
        }
    }
```

Below retrieval is OK from table

```
string query = "select * from Translation where ChapterID = 1";
            List<Translation> listi = dbConn.Query<Translation>(query).ToList();//where ChapterID = " + chapter.SuraID).ToList();
            foreach (Translation li in listi)
            {
                li.ArabicAyaID = ConvertToArabicIndicString(Convert.ToInt16(li.ArabicAyaID));
            }
            return listi;
```

I just modifed it and made a view (class and view have the same column name)

```
public class ArabicTextWithTranslation
    {
        string _ayaID, _arabicAyaTranslation, _arabicAya, _language, _description;
        byte _chapterID, _languageID;
        System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment _hAlignment;

        public string AyaID
        {
            get { return _ayaID; }
            set { _ayaID = value; }
        }
        public string Aya
        {
            get { return _arabicAya; }
            set { _arabicAya = value; }
        }
        public byte ChapterID
        {
            get { return _chapterID; }
            set { _chapterID = value; }
        }
        public System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment HAlignment
        {
            get { return _hAlignment; }
            set { _hAlignment = value; }
        }
        public string ArabicAyaTranslation
        {
            get { return _arabicAyaTranslation; }
            set { _arabicAyaTranslation = value; }
        }
        public byte LanguageID
        {
            get { return _languageID; }
            set { _languageID = value; }
        }
    }
```

The retrieval is below which doesn't work

```
string query = "select Ar.AyaID, Ar.Aya, Ar.ChapterID,Tr.ArabicAyaTranslation from ArabicText as Ar inner join Translation as Tr on Ar.AyaID = Tr.ArabicAyaID and Tr.ChapterID = Ar.ChapterID where Ar.ChapterID = " + chapter.SuraID;
             List<ArabicTextWithTranslation> listi = dbConn.Query<ArabicTextWithTranslation>(query).ToList();//where ChapterID = " + chapter.SuraID).ToList();
             foreach (ArabicTextWithTranslation li in listi)
            {
                li.AyaID = ConvertToArabicIndicString(Convert.ToInt16(li.AyaID));
            }
            return listi;
```

If I remove the column "Tr.ArabicAyaTranslation" from my select statement everything is fine, If I add it, then zero is retrieved. I am storing utf8 chars in that column.

I really don't know what could be the problem? (This query works perfect in sqlite browser and firefox add-ons)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "zero is retrieved"? Do you get the string `"zero"` or `"0"`?

Comment: Thanks, I mean zero record. when I remove that column it retrieve all records, When I add that column than zero record is retrieved.